# How to calculate grand mean and standard deviation for the grouped table?

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot-table

I have this table that I created using the following dplyr code:

**DATA**

```
demo <- structure(list(`Performance-1` = c(4, 5, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 5, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4), `Performance-2` = c(4, 
5, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 5, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 
4, 3, 3), Gender = c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", NA, "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", NA, "Female", NA, "Female", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is just a sample of the main data that I don't have access to. The result below may be different

```
analysis_vars <- c("Performance-1", "Performance-2")

demo %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = analysis_vars,names_to = "Performance") %>% 
  select(Performance, value, Gender) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Gender), Performance %in% c("Performance-1", "Performance-2")) %>%
  group_by(Gender, Performance) %>% 
  summarise(mean = round(mean(value, na.rm=T),2), sd = round(sd(value, na.rm=T),2), N = sum(!is.na(value))) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Gender, values_from = c(mean, sd, N)) 


Performance     mean_Female     mean_Male   sd_Female   sd_Male     N_Female    N_Male
Performance-1   4.14            4.10        0.79        0.79        428         896
Performance-2   4.00            3.91        0.87        0.86        427         897
```

I want to get a grand mean and grand std deviation and as the las row, but I can't figure this out.

When I tried the following code:

```
demo %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = analysis_vars,names_to = "Performance") %>% 
  select(Performance, value, Gender) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Gender), Performance %in% c("Performance-1", "Performance-2")) %>%
  group_by(Gender, Performance) %>% 
  summarise(mean = round(mean(value, na.rm=T),2), sd = round(sd(value, na.rm=T),2), N = sum(!is.na(value))) %>% ungroup() %>%
  add_row(mean = sum(.$mean*.$N)/sum(.$N), sd = sum(.$N-1)*.$sd/sum(.$N)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Gender, values_from = c(mean, sd, N))
```

and the result I got is this:

```
Performance     mean_Female     mean_Male   sd_Female   sd_Male     N_Female    N_Male
Performance-1   <dbl [1]>       <dbl [1]>   <NULL>      <dbl [1]>   <dbl [1]>   <NULL>  
Performance-2   <dbl [1]>       <dbl [1]>   <NULL>      <dbl [1]>   <dbl [1]>   <NULL>
```

When I removed the pivot_wider (the last row) to see what's happening, this is what I see. It seems like it added rows for both Gender.

```
Gender  Performance     mean        sd          N
Female  Performance-1   4.140000    0.7900000   428
Female  Performance-2   4.000000    0.8700000   427
Male    Performance-1   4.100000    0.7900000   896
Male    Performance-2   3.910000    0.8600000   897
NA      NA              4.025978    0.7888066   NA
NA      NA              4.025978    0.8686858   NA
NA      NA              4.025978    0.7888066   NA
NA      NA              4.025978    0.8587009   NA
```

So, I thought perhaps I should do this after pivoting:

```
    demo %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = analysis_vars,names_to = "Performance") %>% 
  select(Performance, value, Gender) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Gender), Performance %in% c("Performance-1", "Performance-2")) %>%
  group_by(Gender, Performance) %>% 
  summarise(mean = round(mean(value, na.rm=T),2), sd = round(sd(value, na.rm=T),2), N = sum(!is.na(value))) %>% ungroup() %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Gender, values_from = c(mean, sd, N)) %>% ungroup() %>%
  add_row(mean_Male = sum(.$mean_Male*.$N_Male)/sum(.$N_Male), 
          mean_Female = sum(.$mean_Female*.$N_Female)/sum(.$N_Female),
          sd_Male = sum(.$N_Male-1)*.$sd_Male/sum(.$N_Male),
          sd_Female = sum(.$N_Female-1)*.$sd_Female/sum(.$N_Female))
```

but I get this

```
Error in vec_rbind(old, new) : Internal error in `vec_assign()`: `value` should have been recycled to fit `x`.
```

I'm not entirely sure what this means. Is there an easier way to calculate the grand mean and sd?

**UPDATE**

I figured out the error above. I was supposed to use `.$N_male` and `.$N_female`. that took care of the error, but it still doesn't produce the result I want. I've fixed the code above.

**UPDATE - 2**

From the table as shown above:

```
Performance     mean_Female     mean_Male   sd_Female   sd_Male     N_Female    N_Male
    Performance-1   4.14            4.10        0.79        0.79        428         896
    Performance-2   4.00            3.91        0.87        0.86        427         897
```

let's calculate the `grand mean`:

```
Female: ((4.14*428)+(4.00*427))/(428+427)
Male: ((4.10*896)+(3.91*897))/(896+897)
```

then for the sd: sqrt(((N1-1)*S1^2+(N2-1)*S2^2+(N3-1)*S3^2)/(N1+N2+N3-3))

```
sd_Female: ((428-1)*0.79+(427-1)*0.87)/(428+427-2)
sd_Female: ((896-1)*0.79+(897-1)*0.86)/(896+897-2)

Performance     mean_Female     mean_Male   sd_Female   sd_Male     N_Female    N_Male
Performance-1   4.14            4.10        0.79        0.79        428         896
Performance-2   4.00            3.91        0.87        0.86        427         897
Grand Mean      4.07            4.00        0.83        0.83
```

I'm not sure what to do with the N_male and female yet, so I don't mind either way - null or some calc.

Comment: So after doing `pivot_wider` do you want to add a new row with column-wise mean for mean column and column-wise `sd` for sd columns?

Comment: @RonakShah, sort of. I think for the grand mean, the mean for each row has to be calculated by N for that row since the n is different. Using the formula `Pooled mean = (N1*M1+N2*M2+N3*M3)/(N1+N2+N3)` and `Pooled SD ={ (N1-1)*S1+(N2-1)*S2+(N3-1)S3}/(N1+N2+N3-3)`. So, a custom calculation. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you make this question reproducible, add sample data and show expected output so that it is easier to understand what are you trying to do?

Comment: data is the table that I added above. I'll update the question with the expected output.

Comment: I don't see where is the reproducible data in your post. By reproducible data I mean something which we can copy-paste into our R session and use it to verify our answer possibly using `dput`, in your case `dput(demo)`. Here is a good guide which tells how to do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269

Comment: @RonakShah, I got it! The actual data is probably not needed for this purpose. Because I generally don't have access to the data. The means should be calculated based on the table above. But I'll try to get that added.

Comment: I think actual data is needed because the calculation you are trying to get should be done before the `pivot_wider` step rather than after. It would be very convoluted if we do it after `pivot_wider` step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the calculation needs to be done before we get data in wide format. Here I suggest two approaches, you can select the one which suits you.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

demo %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Performance'),names_to = "Performance") %>% 
   select(Performance, value, Gender) %>%
   filter(!is.na(Gender), Performance %in% c("Performance-1", "Performance-2")) %>%
   group_by(Gender, Performance) %>% 
   summarise(mean = round(mean(value, na.rm=T),2), 
             sd = round(sd(value, na.rm=T),2), 
             N = sum(!is.na(value))) %>%
   mutate(gm = sum(mean * N)/sum(N), 
          gsd = sum((N - 1) * sd)/sum(N - n())) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = Gender, values_from = c(mean, sd, N, gm, gsd)) 


# A tibble: 2 x 11
#  Performance   mean_Female mean_Male sd_Female sd_Male N_Female N_Male gm_Female gm_Male gsd_Female gsd_Male
#  <chr>               <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>    <int>  <int>     <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 Performance-1         4        4.06      0.71    0.77        5     16       3.9    4.03       1.03    0.852
#2 Performance-2         3.8      4         0.84    0.82        5     16       3.9    4.03       1.03    0.852
```

Here, we can see that the value of `gm` and `gsd` are in their separate columns and are repeated.

---

The second approach closer to your expected output shown is in two-step.

```
demo %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Performance'),names_to = "Performance") %>% 
  select(Performance, value, Gender) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Gender), Performance %in% c("Performance-1", "Performance-2")) %>%
  group_by(Gender, Performance) %>% 
  summarise(mean = round(mean(value, na.rm=T),2), 
            sd = round(sd(value, na.rm=T),2), 
            N = sum(!is.na(value))) -> p


p %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = Gender, values_from = c(mean, sd, N)) %>%
   bind_rows(p %>%
              summarise(mean = sum(mean * N)/sum(N), 
              sd = sum((N - 1) * sd)/sum(N - n()), 
              Performance = 'Total') %>%
              pivot_wider(names_from = Gender, values_from = c(mean, sd)))



# Performance   mean_Female mean_Male sd_Female sd_Male N_Female N_Male
#  <chr>               <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>    <int>  <int>
#1 Performance-1         4        4.06      0.71   0.77         5     16
#2 Performance-2         3.8      4         0.84   0.82         5     16
#3 Total                 3.9      4.03      1.03   0.852       NA     NA
```

Comment: thanks. this looks good. I also came with a similar conclusion. I posted my answer above. But I think your second solution is better.

Answer (score 1):

This maybe one approach albeit using expss for calculations then converting output to data.frame I think achieves what you are looking for.

```
library (expss)
library (dplyr)

demo %>% 
tidyr::gather(key,value,-Gender) %>% #get long
tab_cells(value) %>% #variable used for calculations
tab_rows(key,total(label = "Grand mean") %>% #total gets grand total
tab_cols(Gender) %>% #variable for cols
tab_stat_fun(Mean =mean,SD = sd,N = w_n, method =list) %>% #calculations
tab_pivot()%>% #makes a table
data.frame() %>% # convert to df
select(c(1,2,5,3,6,4,7)) -> out #order cols

#tidy up names
colnames(out) <-gsub("Gender[.]","",colnames(out))
colnames(out)[1] <- "Performance"
out
```

Answer (score 1):

After much trial-errors and thoughts, I have come to one solution that seems to be working. I still welcome an elegant solution for this:

```
p2 <- demo %>% pivot_longer(cols = analysis_vars, names_to = "Performance") %>% 
    select(Performance, value, !!var) %>%
    filter(!is.na(!!var), Performance %in% c("Performance-1", "Performance-2")) %>%
    group_by(!!var, Performance) %>% 
    summarise(mean = round(mean(value, na.rm=T),2), sd = round(sd(value, na.rm=T),2), N = sum(!is.na(value))) %>% 
    mutate(gm = round(sum(mean*N)/sum(N),2),
           gsd = round(sqrt(sum((N-1)*sd^2)/sum(N-5)),2)) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = !!var, values_from = c(mean, sd, N, gm, gsd))


  g <- p2 %>% select(matches("gm_|gsd_"))

  n <- g %>% rename_all(funs(str_replace(., "gm_", "mean_"))) %>% 
    rename_all(funs(str_replace(., "gsd_", "sd_"))) %>% 
    summarise_all(mean, na.rm=T) %>% 
    add_column(Item = "Grand Mean/SD", .before = 1)

p2 <- p2 %>% 
          bind_rows(n) %>%           
          select(-starts_with("gm_"), -starts_with("gsd_"))
```

So far, this is the only way I have been able to come up.

I needed it this way to put in the excel spreadsheet as a table with the means.

Answer (score 1):

Well now that I better understand your desires.  I still think letting one of the existing packages do the work is smart...

```r
library(tables)

tabular( table = (Species + 1) ~ (n = 1) + Format(digits = 2) * (Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Width + Petal.Length) * (mean + sd), 
         data = iris )
#>                                                                    
#>                 Sepal.Length      Sepal.Width      Petal.Width     
#>  Species    n   mean         sd   mean        sd   mean        sd  
#>  setosa      50 5.01         0.35 3.43        0.38 0.25        0.11
#>  versicolor  50 5.94         0.52 2.77        0.31 1.33        0.20
#>  virginica   50 6.59         0.64 2.97        0.32 2.03        0.27
#>  All        150 5.84         0.83 3.06        0.44 1.20        0.76
#>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different `tidyverse` approach that I usually choose for this kind of problems. It is based on creating a nested tibble together with a list of filter expressions. The last filter expression is `1 > 0` by which all the data is included for the 'grand mean'. For your problem at hand this approach might be overly verbose, but when you have more filter conditions, especially when working with different subsets of your data, or when you have either many or more complicated summary statistics, this approach should be more flexible than both the `add_row` and the `tabular` approach.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# your data
demo <- structure(list(`Performance-1` = c(4, 5, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4,  4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 5, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4),
                       `Performance-2` = c(4, 5, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 5, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3),
                        Gender = c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male",
                                   NA, "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", NA, "Female", NA, "Female", "Male", "Male",
                                   "Male", "Male", NA)),
                  row.names = c(NA, -25L),
                  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

analysis_vars <- c("Performance-1", "Performance-2")

demo_dat <- demo %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = analysis_vars,names_to = "Performance") %>% 
  select(Performance, value, Gender) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Gender), Performance %in% c("Performance-1", "Performance-2"))

# From here new approach
res <- tibble(filter_expr = list(Male = expr(Gender == "Male"),
                                 Female = expr(Gender == "Female"),
                                `Grand Mean`= expr(1 > 0))) %>% 
        crossing(data = list(demo_dat)) %>% 
         mutate(id = names(filter_expr),
                data = map2(data,
                            filter_expr,
                            ~ .x %>% filter(eval(.y)) %>% 
                              group_by(Performance) %>% 
                              summarise(mean = round(mean(value, na.rm = T), 2), 
                                        sd = round(sd(value, na.rm = T), 2), 
                                        N = sum(!is.na(value))))) %>% 
      select(-filter_expr) %>% 
      unnest(cols = data) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Performance", values_from = c(mean, sd, N)) 

res
#> # A tibble: 3 x 7
#>   id    `mean_Performan… `mean_Performan… `sd_Performance… `sd_Performance…
#>   <chr>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
#> 1 Male              4.06             4                0.77             0.82
#> 2 Fema…             4                3.8              0.71             0.84
#> 3 Gran…             4.05             3.95             0.74             0.8 
#> # … with 2 more variables: `N_Performance-1` <int>, `N_Performance-2` <int>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>